# How do you reference a resource name in a deployIfNotExists azure policy?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

Below is a sample azure policy json that looks at all the storage accounts and deployIfNotExists the allowBlobPublicAccess settings to true. How do you ensure that the name field in every arm template gets the name of storage account resource?

Some additional context: Template Functions [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#resourceid) does not seem to work well. If trying to use resourceId().resourceName1, I get an error

> InvalidTemplate Message   Deployment template validation failed: 'The
> template resource '[resourceId().resourceName1]' at line '1' and
> column '207' is not valid: Unable to evaluate template language
> function 'resourceId': function requires at least '2' argument(s)
> while '0' were provided. Please see
> https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#resourceid for usage
> details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage
> details.'.

```
{
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "deployIfNotExists",
          "details": {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "existenceCondition": {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/allowBlobPublicAccess",
                  "equals": "true"
                }
              ]
            },
            "roleDefinitionIds": [
              "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
            ],
            "deployment": {
              "properties": {
                "mode": "incremental",
                "template": {
                  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                  "resources": [
                    {
                      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                      "name": **"[resourceId().name]",**
                      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
                      "location": "canadacentral",
                      "properties": {
                         "allowBlobPublicAccess": "true"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "parameters": {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function

> field(fieldName)

to access properties of the currently evaluated resource.
This is from the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure):

> field(fieldName)
> fieldName: [Required] string - Name of the field to retrieve
> Returns the value of that field from the resource that is being evaluated by the If condition.
> field is primarily used with AuditIfNotExists and DeployIfNotExists to reference fields on the resource that are being evaluated. An example of this use can be seen in the DeployIfNotExists example.

You can see a sample deployIfNotExists policy [here](https://github.com/Azure/Community-Policy/blob/53c5f27699d149eeb2f554e7f62b2dd6b5ce1817/Policies/App%20Service/functionapp-enforce-https-only-dine/azurepolicy.json).